# questions about multiple eclipse with android SDK and its trick

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an existing android SDK installed for one eclipse. Now, i want to install IBM Worklight, which need an android SDK (so two plugin in one eclipse). I install the IBM Worklight in the second eclipse (So now i have two eclipse in my system, one for android, and one for IBM, but the IBM is not yet working because it also needs android SDK).

My questions are :

1. Can i do something like, going to where my android SDK stored (in C in my case), then archieved it (.zip) and use this zip to another eclipse (so i dont need to download the SDK again for the second eclipse)
2. Continued from number 1, is there any way so i dont have to install the android SDK/ADT again in my second eclipse?(so i need to take it from the first eclipse)
3. Is it possible to only have one eclipse to produce two different products (i mean having 2 plugin, IBM Worklight and Android)?Please kindly tell me your experience if you can do this. I asked you because the last time i tried to install two plugin in one eclipse, my eclipse is not working (Android and BB <10 plugin)
4. Can i connect two eclipse to one android SDK folder?

Thanks for your help,i need to ask those questions because my internet connection's speed is not good, so downloading the SDK again will take some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with having both Google's ADT plug-in and IBM Worklight's Worklight Studio plug-in in the same Eclipse is long solved.

So, just have one Eclipse with both plug-ins installed. The recommended set-up is: Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 (Juno SR2), IBM Worklight v5.0.6.1

Also, the Android SDK is not part of your ADT installation, so yes, you can basically have 2 Eclipses both using the same Android SDK path, however, ADT is an Eclipse plug-in, so if you have 2 Eclipses, you must also install ADT for it.

Comment: Thanks very much. So, (just to make sure) in my case, the best way is to have only on eclipse right?

Comment: I only know that if you use the latest Worklight version, your "case" is a no-case, because it won't happen to begin with.